# Olympic Problem about Theory of numbers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Let $Y=\{1,2,\ldots, 2014\} \subset \mathbb{N}$. Find the maximal subset $A\subset Y$ such that,
>   $$\forall x\in A,\quad x\not\mid\sum_{y\in A\setminus\{x\}} y.$$

Example, $A'=\{2,4,6,\ldots,2014\}\cup\{5\}$ this set holds the conditions, but ins't the maximal subset.

Comment: Maximal in the sense of set inclusion, or the size of the set? If the former, there might be more than one maximal set.

Comment: To clarify the condition: no element can divide the sum of the others.

Comment: Let be $S$ the sum of the elements of $A$. If $x\in A$ does not divide the sum of the others, then $x$ does not divide $S$.

Comment: Maximal in the sense of cardinal. i.e., $|A|$ is maximum.

Comment: Which olympiad was it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, $1\notin A$. And $Y\setminus\{1\}$ does not meet the condition.

$A=Y\setminus\{1,13\}$. The sum of the elements of $A$ ($p=2,029,091$) is prime.

Let $x\in A$. Since $x$ is not $1$ and certainly is not $p$, we have that $x$ does not divide $p$.

Since $x$ does not divide $p$, $x$ does not divide $p-x$. But
$$p-x=\sum_{y\in A\setminus\{x\}} y$$

Comment: Maybe you make your answer self-contained, by including your third comment?

Comment: This is correct, why is it voted down? The set $A$ cannot contain $1$, obviously, and it is enough to remove one other number such that the sum of the remaining is a prime.

Comment: Simply thinking loud: how can this problem be solved without a big enough prime table?

Comment: After catching the "trick" of one, and only taking care the sum is a prime big enough, the answer (assuming it indeed is a prime. I didn't check) is obviously correct. The downvote is probably due to the fact that some rush to downvote, whether the answer is right or wrong. Some slack would be nice even for wrong answers: people can either fix or delete.

Comment: @ajotatxe Thta's a good question. How do you figure out what number you subtract such that the difference is a prime in a competition environment, when time is of essence? Clearly you have to subtract an odd number, but even getting to 13, checking by hand would take awhile.

Comment: @Markus Perhaps, with Euler's memory... lol

Comment: If you subtract 5, you get 2029099=1009*2011. Good luck checking that the number is NOT prime by hand! Maybe there is another way to solve this.

Comment: @ajotatxe You rule out the evens, multiples of 3 and 5. If you remember the test for 7,11,13 that helps. So you have to deal with 2029103,2029099,2029091. The first is easy, you soon hit 17. The second is less easy. You might get it by adding $501^2=251001$. Then the prime. You have to rule out primes less than 1424 that is 224 primes. We must be missing something. That is unreasonable for a contest with max time per question around an hour.

Comment: This problem seems too long and too easy for a contest. In some countries, the local stage of Math Ol. has problems of similar difficulty, and calculators are allowed. In any case, I find it terribly ugly for an Olympiad.

Comment: it is easy if you have a computer or a primes table. There must be a solution that does not rely on that, which might be hard.

Comment: Perhaps using a Miller Rabin test or Fermat test, it can be done relatively quickly. The Fermat test would suffice if one knew 2029091 was not Carmichael.

Comment: If you started from the other end, you would try deducting 1+2013, then 1+2011. That would give you 2027091 divisible by 3, then 2027093, which is prime. But that hardly helps.